# Link multiple accounts iOS app - Firebase/Facebook Login & XCode/Swift 5

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I'm building this app for a client (It's a basic scheduling app like HootSuite but simpler) and he wants the ability to add multiple Facebook accounts with an IAP (aka In-App Purchase) after said IAP is purchased. The IAP is all done and works great but I cannot figure out how to link multiple Facebook accounts. I tried to use the same login method that a previous developer used (It's an ongoing freelance project and 2 other devs worked on it before I joined) to no avail since the login process stops once the app realizes that the user has already signed in...

**So I guess that my question is this: Is there a way to link multiple Facebook accounts at once in a single iOS app? If so, how exactly? Forget the IAPs if that's too confusing, everything is fine there anyways. The goal is to be as seamless as possible, so ideally there would be no need for the user to log out and log back into the other account (Something I've seen a lot in other Questions/Answers).**

I don't think I am authorized to show the code to you guys (that would also require sharing the entire project, it's a real spider-web!), but could someone please lead me in the right direction?

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Thank you in advance.

Notes:

1. Just like the title says, we use Firebase for our storage, Cloud Firestore for our database and Facebook login (through Firebase) for login since the purpose of the app is to schedule posts on IG.
2. I use a basic variable called "activeUsers" to track the number of accounts "linked" to the app so we can know whether or not to show the "PurchaseModel" and, obviously, receipt verification and all that for IAPs. Thought it could be useful!

**3. When the app starts, you are prompted to link a Facebook account to enable the scheduler. THIS WORKS GREAT! What I am trying to achieve is to add other accounts AFTER the first one has been "enabled"/logged into.**

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to link multiple accounts from the same provider to a single Firebase Auth account.

You can only link multiple accounts of different types (Facebook, Google, GitHub, etc) to a single Firebase account as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking).